# Turn off/modify specific pre-rendered Gutenberg editor CSS styles

Tags: css, block-editor

I'm having an issue where Gutenberg is pre-rendering with the theme's `style.css`, and some of the styles are not fit for the editor. Specifically, I have a class that utilizes `transform: translate` which basically slides the block off of the page in the back end.

It should be simple enough to add CSS for Gutenberg to stop rendering this in the back end, but I'm struggling.

My class of `.bg` has transform on it, so I placed `.editor-styles-wrapper .bg` in my `style.css` with `transform: unset;` which does nothing. I've also tried `transform: none;` which does nothing as well.

I thought maybe something was getting stuck in cache so I've refreshed and refreshed, but it's the most recent stylesheet. I also added `editor-style.css` using `add_theme_support('editor-styles')` in `functions.php` which has the same result of nothing.

I have tried `.bg:not(.editor-styles-wrapper)` in the `style.css` which also does nothing. I have tried even `#editor .bg` which again, just does nothing. I have tried removing the transform from the `.bg` class just in `styles.css` itself to see if there's something being cached or it's getting it from elsewhere, which did work. I've tried placing each bit of CSS to the end of the stylesheet, which had no effect as well.

Any ideas on this one? I'm stumped.

Comment: you shouldn't be manually adding `.editor-styles-wrapper` into your stylesheets, WP will read in the CSS file and automatically add it in when you add it as an editor stylesheet, replacing any `html`/`body` rules accordingly. It's more likely that because of this your CSS doesn't apply to the rule once it's transformed, and doing what your question asks means that instead of incorrect rules, no rules of any kind would be applied and you wouldn't get what you wanted]

Comment: also note that it's probably a little more complicated than this given that you're wanting to use `transform` since CSS transforms are used to animate the movement of blocks. What are you trying to do to items with that class that requires it?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I found was to target my body ID on the front end so the back end does not apply this to `.editor-styles-wrapper`. What I end up with is `#ContainerID .bg` which seems to function properly.